# What would be the best way to go about converting this list of data to dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, hashmap

I have a rough idea of how I can do this but **unsure where to start implementing**. Looking for **tips and advice please**.

I want to convert data 1, key value tuple pairs, into data 2, a dictionary.

Data 1:

```
[
    ('category0[title]', 'dinner'), 
    ('category0[items][][name]', 'chicken'), 
    ('category0[items][][name]', 'steak'), 
    ('category0[items][][price]', '19'), 
    ('category0[items][][price]', '79'), 
    ('category0[items][][description]', 'oven roasted chicken'), 
    ('category0[items][][description]', 'wagyu steak and fries'), 
    ('category1[title]', 'dessert'), 
    ('category1[items][][name]', 'cookies'), 
    ('category1[items][][price]', '3'), 
    ('category1[items][][description]', 'chocolate chip')
]
```

Data 2

```
[
    {
        'category-title': 'dinner',
        'items': [
            {
                'item-name': 'chicken',
                'item-price': '19',
                'item-description': 'oven roasted chicken'
            },
            {
                'item-name': 'steak',
                'item-price': '79',
                'item-description': 'wagyu steak and fries'
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        'category-title': 'dessert',
        'items': [
            {
                'item-name': 'cookies',
                'item-price': '3',
                'item-description': 'chocolate chip'
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Constraints:

- For there to be another dictionary in the list, there must be another category title entered
- The only variable is the number of items, but each item will have a name, price, and description

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Any specific problems? The main tricky part here is dealing with the repeating field names corresponding to separate items - are the fields always in the order you describe? Do all items always have the same fields?

Comment: i tried 2 or 3 different methods, but they didnt accomplish enough to attach here. I was having trouble dealing with overwriting values since there are repeating keys. The fields are always in the same order, the only variable is the number of each.

Comment: For this input, what should the result be? What do you think are the logical steps to solving the problem? What parts of that can't you figure out how to do? "I was having trouble dealing with overwriting values since there are repeating keys" Well, yes; a `dict` in Python **cannot have** duplicate keys.

Comment: Even though your solutions didn't work, it's still [customary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to attach what you thought might have worked. It allows people to see what level of understanding you already have and what you're aiming for - as well as showing that you at least made an effort, instead of expecting others to do the work for you

Comment: You should also think more about your input format. For example, where you have `category0[items][][name]`, *how is the code supposed to know* that the `[]` part means "possibly append an element to a list, or possibly use an existing element", rather than "use a dict key equal to `''`"? How does it decide whether to append an element or not? If it doesn't append an element, which existing element should it use?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think that was sufficiently clear to OP, from the example data above it's likely due to the repeating key values that should translate to new items, I don't the problem is OP doesn't get that, they just don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Are you expecting the input data to have a neat order like this, always? What should happen if the tuples are in a different order?

Comment: @grismar youre right thats fair, im going to work at it a bit more and ill provide more of my own code to start off with

Comment: Why did you build data 1 in the first place if data 2 is what you want?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy, data1 is what im receiving from an html POST request, i need to convert it to data2 to work with in python

Comment: That seems like something that should be mentioned and tagged in the question. HTML POST is probably standardized and probably you're not the first person ever to have this need, so rather than making it look like a custom problem needing a custom solution, it should probably be solved with some existing library already written for the standard task

Comment: Just to clarify somethings. Wizard, this is technically a Http post request, not html. @KellyBundy, Http is standardized in how it sends and receives data but has no standard for how data should be formatted. RESTful extended Http to have JSON be standard but some people have used XML or other types. So no there is no standard for this. However, if we knew what program generated this output it will most likely have the format's name which can then be researched and maybe someone has indeed created a library for it.

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide Yes, that's why I said probably and wasn't very specific, just repeating what they said. Whether it's in the http standard or some other standard/software isn't that relevant. My point is what you said at the end, they should tell us the origin and then the corresponding parser can be looked up and used. People *creating* data/formats are interested in having the formatted data be used, and thus usually provide ways to facilitate that.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to transform data from one format to another it's best to take it in steps so that it's easier to follow.

How I look at it is that each part of the string is a attribute to access the object and that the first part of the string is unique and so it can be used as a key. So I did the transform in three steps.

1. Convert the string to a tuple containing the key and the individual parts and the value. So `('category0[items][][name]', 'chicken')` turns into `('category0', 'items', '', 'name', 'chicken')`
2. Using the `categoryX` as a key, create a `dict` to hold the tuples for that specific key. `('category0', 'items', '', 'name', 'chicken')` becomes `dict['category0'].append(('items', '', 'name', 'chicken'))`. Making sure to add a check to see if the key is already in the dict or not to avoid overwriting data or getting `KeyError`.
3. Using that `dict` convert the tuple to `dict` that is returned and added to a list to contain all items.

```
# Convert the string of "category0[items][][name]" to a list of attributes so we can work with it easier.
def split_attrs_to_list(item_list: list[tuple[str, str]]) -> list[tuple[str]]:
    attr_value_list = []

    for attr_value in item_list:
        # Split by '[' and then replace ']' with an empty string to remove all brackets and have a list of attributes
        attributes = tuple(_str.replace(']', '') for _str in attr_value[0].split('[')) + (attr_value[1],)
        attr_value_list.append(attributes)

    return attr_value_list


# Using the first part of the attributes as a key we can find distinct item from the list and add them to a dict
def distinct_items_by_key(attrs_value_list: list[tuple[str]]) -> dict[str, list[tuple[str]]]:
    attrs_value_dict = dict()

    for attrs_value in attrs_value_list:

        key = attrs_value[0]
        if key not in attrs_value_dict:
            attrs_value_dict[key] = list()

        attrs_value_dict[key].append(attrs_value[1:])

    return attrs_value_dict


# Parse the list of attributes, build a dict and add the attributes and values to the dict
def parse(attrs_value: list[tuple[str]]):
    obj = dict()

    title = attrs_value[0][1]
    items = []
    item_tuples = attrs_value[1:]

    # Since there is only 3 attributes for a given "item" we can divide by 3 and know exactly how many items there are
    item_count = len(item_tuples) // 3
    
    # Use offsets to grab that appropriate value
    for i in range(item_count):
        item_name = item_tuples[i * 3][-1]
        item_price = item_tuples[i * 3 + 1][-1]
        item_description = item_tuples[i * 3 + 2][-1]

        items.append({'item-name': item_name, 'item-price': item_price, 'item-description': item_description})

    obj['category-title'] = title
    obj['items'] = items

    return obj


def convert_to_dict(item_list: list[tuple[str, str]]):
    attrs_value_list = split_attrs_to_list(item_list)
    distinct_items = distinct_items_by_key(attrs_value_list)

    parsed_items = [parse(item) for item in distinct_items.values()]

    # Add code here to use parsed_items


convert_to_dict(input_list)
```